# Using !empty to show different html/php code in a php template?

Tags: php, html, is-empty

I'm trying to make it so if user does not write anything in the box for their first name, the template will automatically make the title of the portal "Jack Smith's Portal".

Otherwise, their name will show their name they typed in's Portal. My attempt, in that pastie, has failed.

I've never done PHP before, this is quite confusing. :P

My poor attempt at this that does not work at all:

section of index.html

```
<form action="template.php" method="post">
<br><p><b>Your first name</b>: 
<input type="text" name="fullname"></p>
<p><b>Your last name</b>: 
<input type="text" name="lastname"></p>
<br>
[etc]
</form>
```

section of template.php

```
<title>
    <?php if (!empty($_POST["fullname"]))> 
    Jack Smith's Portal

    <?php else: ?>  

    <?php echo $_POST["fullname"]; ?> <?php echo $_POST["lastname"]; ?>'s Portal 

    <?php endif ?>
</title>
```

Also, for the php else section, say I wanted to put a whole chunk of html code including multiple php echo $_POST sections, but is all determined based off one "lastname" from the php if !empty section - what would that look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your logic is backward. You want to display the default text `Jack Smith's Portal` if `$_POST["fullname"]` is not provided. `empty` returns true if a value is empty. Negating that with `!` in your if condition means "If the value *is not* empty".

Try:

```
<?php if ( empty($_POST["fullname"]) ) : ?>
```

Also, I correct a syntax error on that line, you had:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST["fullname"]))>
```

Your closing tag should be `?>` and you're missing the `:` after the if statement.